# What is a nested pattern in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, nested, pattern-matching, design-patterns, ghc

What is a **'nested'** pattern in Haskell. I hear the term everywhere but am not sure what the it actually means. How would you define it? Any examples?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED TO ADD: (as quoted in textbook on request)

"Patterns can contain literals and nested patterns, as in the examples:

```
addPair (0,y) = y

addPair (x,y) = x+y


shift :: ((Int,Int),Int) -> (Int,(Int,Int))

shift ((x,y),z) = (x,(y,z))
```

Comment: I'm guessing it might have something to do with the recursive logic that is used heavily in Haskell.

Comment: @Pieter should be simpler than that

Comment: Care to cite an example of what you hear? To my knowledge, there is no canonical meaning attached to this term.

Comment: ok @Ingo and @Pieter read above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that you can match against a pattern that contains another pattern. In your example, the `(x, y)` pattern is contained inside the larger `((x, y), z)` pattern. The nesting can be arbitrarily deep, e.g. all of the following are legal:

```
f    ((x2,x0),x1)                 = ()
f'   (((x3, x2),x0),x1)           = ()
f''  ((((x4,x3), x2),x0),x1)      = ()
f''' (((((x5,x4),x3), x2),x0),x1) = ()
```

and so on. This also extends to lists and algebraic datatypes:

```
f  [[x]]   = ()
f' [[[x]]] = ()

g  (Just (Just x))        = ()
g' (Just (Just (Just x))) = ()
```

Here, `f` takes a list of lists, `f'` takes a list of lists of lists, `g` takes a `Maybe` that contains another `Maybe`(that is, `Maybe (Maybe a)`), and `g'` takes a `Maybe (Maybe (Maybe a))`

Comment: ah, I'm starting to get it now ;)

Comment: Note that this is an unhappy wording, IMHO - because nesting is usually associated with lexical scopes but variables in patterns must be linear no matter how deeply "nested" the pattern is. Hence, the term  *sub-pattern* may be  better (in analogy to *sub-expressions*).

Comment: These really are nesting rather than "sub-pattern". That is, the pattern matching really proceeds by matching a nested data value. "sub-patterns" in regular expressions are still matching a linear sequence of characters. Here, a nested pattern must actually match a nested data structure, not a linear one.

Answer (score 0):

Though I may be wrong, I can only assume from context that an "unnested" pattern would be something like `addPair x = x` or `addPair x y = x+y`. Your arguments I believe are a pattern. In most programming languages, this would be a simple `x y`. while in this case you your argument pattern can be more complicated, e.g. `(x, y)` or `((x, y), z)`.

Nesting probably means "a tuple or list" or "a nonflat tuple or list".